# Algebraic dual $E^*$ separates $E$?

Tags: vector-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $E$ be a vector space over a field $F$.
Let $E^*:=\{f:E\rightarrow F : f \text{ is linear}\}$ be the *algebraic dual* of $E$. Suppose $E^*\ne \{0\}$ (i.e. take for granted the axiom of choice).

Is it always true that $E^*$ separates $E$ ? i.e. is it true that
$$
\forall x\in E\backslash\{0\}, \; \exists f \in E^* \; s.t. \; f(x)\ne 0 \; \text{?}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because there exists a subspace $E'$ of $E$ such that $E=Fx\oplus E'$.
Then $Fx\to F:ax\mapsto a$ and $0:E'\to F$ extends to a unique $F$-linear map $f:E\to F$ such that $f(x)=1\neq 0$.

Comment: That looks good. But why does there exists $E'<E$ s.t. $E=F\langle x \rangle \oplus E'$ ?

Comment: Because $E$ is a free $F$-module, that's each subspace is a direct summand. In term of basis, there exists a basis of $E$ over $F$ containing $x$.

Comment: Yep ok. I just realized that every $E$ admits a basis (assuming AC) when reading Mees de Vries comment. I though some vector spaces $E$ didn't admit a basis, intuitively because some prehilbert spaces don't admit prehilbert basis (but in fact they do admit a basis, which is not necessarily orthogonal). Thanks, things make sense now.

Answer (score 1):

With the axiom of choice: fixing $x$, find a basis $\{x\} \cup \{e_i\}_{i \in I}$ of $E$, so that each element of $E$ can be written uniquely as $\alpha x + \sum_{i \in I} \lambda_i e_i$, with only finitely many $\lambda_i$ unequal to 0. Now define
$$
f\left(\alpha x + \sum_{i \in I} \lambda_i e_i \right) = \alpha.
$$
Then $f \in E^*$ and $f(x) = 1 \neq 0$.

Comment: That seems good also. But why does $E$ admits a basis ?

Comment: Follows from AC: there is a standard proof from Zorn's lemma. In fact it is equivalent to AC, though the converse is much trickier.